# Moving Laravel from Windows to Linux Server

Tags: php, linux, windows, laravel, cpanel

I am new in Laravel, I made an small website with Laravel on My Windows 8.1 , And Now I zipped that website folder (xampp/htdocs/mysite ) and named mysite.zip

I uploaded that website to my Linux server and putted on a subdomain: 
**test.example.com/mysite/public/**

and I have a route to return a test string. But laravel throwout an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/qmelkir/public_html/test/zanbil/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 426

Questions:

1-What is the problem?

2-How can I have access to composer on my Linux server (I have access by cPanel)?

3-I had installed Laravel **Intervention Image class** by composer on my windows, Does this or other classes that I installed by composer works when I move website?

Comment: Looks like your PHP version is to old. What are you running? PHP 5.4 is required.

Comment: @lukasgeiter thanks for your answers again. Let me check

Comment: @lukasgeiter oops, You are right my PHP version is **5.3.27**, I should test it on another server. Do you know any server to test it for free?

Comment: Puh not really. I personally use a paid hosting...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set the version of my php in the .htaccess file with this line:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php